# Trouble opening port 30000 in Arris

Tags: networking, port, router, portforwarding

I'm trying to run a server of an old game, the server is running well, I can connect to it using the 127.0.0.1 with no problems, but I can't get it to be externally acessed, it uses the 30000 port. I'm using a Arris TG862 router by the way

Here's what I did after some search:

- I went to the 192.168.0.1 configuration page, went to LAN Setup -> DHCP and there I did set a new fixed DHCP adress. To do this, I did copy the MAC corresponding to my PC and the IP Adress from the list, only changing the last number of the IP Adress (from 5 to 9).
- I went to my Network Settings and changed the IP Adress to use the static, I also did copy the previous Gateway/DNS Servers. After that, I tried connecting to my server using the new static ip 192.168.0.9, and **it did work**, so the static ip is ok I guess.
- Now I went back to the 192.168.0.1 page, and entered the Firewall -> Port triggers,  I created a trigger for the port 30000-30000, for both TCP and UDP.
- Firewall -> Virtual Servers. There I created a Virtual Server for the port 30000-30000, and for both types. I used my new static ip adress for the Private IP Adress.
- After all this, I tried acessing using my external ip adress (got it from whatismyip.com). For my frustration, it didn't work. I also tried restarting both the internet and my PC but yeah, no results. I also downloaded that portforwarding.com's tool (not sure if this is legit tho) and checked it says my port 30000 still isn't open

So, does anyone know what I may have done wrong or have some idea? I'm really inexperienced in port forwarding. Any input is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem like that today. After spending 2 hours trying to port forward some ports, for a client of mine, I decided to call their ISP to see if it was their problem. Turns out I didn't do anything wrong and it was the ISP's problem since they've put my client in a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). Since they didn't have a public IP, port forward would not work.

After the ISP gave my client a public IP, it still didn't work, for my client's LAN.Turns out I was able to access the ports from other networks but not from that LAN.The reason was a thing called [Hairpining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) that was not enabled or supported by my client's router.

In conclusion:

1. See if it is your ISP's problem
2. Try to see if you can access it from another network (or from http://www.canyouseeme.org/)